# Can A215366 be used to approximate primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

This sequence has always fascinated me for a number :) of reasons but mainly because of the way it organizes the natural numbers. It looks to have a structure of the positive solutions of two tangent functions 90 degrees off from each other. Is there a reason that this would not be able to be approximated or calculated with a function? The only reason I ask is if you can find all the solutions for when you get a power of two then you can take that $n$ and add 1 to get the prime solution or an approximation to a prime.

[Link to number sequence page](https://oeis.org/A215366)

[image]

Comment: If there exists a formula that can approximate there number sequence then it would also work to approximate primes. The reason I am asking about this sequence is because the structure looks like something a function could generate.

Comment: I mean you would be able to approximate the $n$-th prime

Comment: The prime number theorem gives a very good approximation of the $n$-th prime for large $n$. Google prime counting function, the $n$-th-prime function is just the inverse and a rough approximation is $p_n\approx n\cdot \ln(n)$

Comment: Thanks,  I know of the prime counting function